# My calculus method of finding the circumference of a circle gives $16r-8r\sqrt{2}$. Where's my mistake?

Tags: calculus, geometry

To find the circumference of a circle using calculus, I've seen the approach of starting with $(ds)^2 = (dx)^2 + (dy)^2$, but my approach should work, too.

I take a small slice of the circle $dθ$. I take the radius on a point $θ$ and $θ + dθ$. I suppose that $ds$ is the base of an isosceles triangle with the other two sides being equal to $r$. Ι take the height and find that $ds = 2r\sin(θ/2)$. I integrate up to $\pi/2$, and I multiply by $4$. The result is equal to $16r-8r\sqrt{2}$. It's very wrong, but I can't see the mistake in my thought process.

EDIT: After getting some help from the comments I think I found the solution.
I, once again, take a small slice of the circle $dθ$. I take the radius on a point $θ$ and $θ + Δθ$. I throw out the isosceles triangle idea because while Δθ tends to 0 the angle that r and Δs form tends to $π\over2$.

So:
$$S(Δθ + θ) - S(θ)=4r*sin(Δθ)$$ 
$$\frac{S(Δθ + θ) - S(θ)}{Δθ}=4\frac{r*sin(Δθ)}{Δθ}$$
$$\lim_{Δθ\to 0}\frac{S(Δθ + θ) - S(θ)}{Δθ}=4\lim_{Δθ\to 0}\frac{r*sin(Δθ)}{Δθ}$$
$$\frac{dS}{dθ}=4r\lim_{Δθ\to 0}\frac{sin(Δθ)}{Δθ}$$
$$\frac{dS}{dθ}=4r$$
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{dS}{dθ}dθ=4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}rdθ $$
$$S = 4r\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$S = 2\pi r$$

Comment: The angle is $\rm{d}\theta$ not $\theta.$

Comment: Informally, $\sin ({1 \over 2} d \theta) = {1 \over 2} d \theta$.

Comment: How did you get to that conclusion? dθ is close to 0 shouldn't $sin({1\over 2 }dθ) = 0$??

Comment: "$d\theta$ is close to $0$ shouldn't $\sin(\frac12d\theta)=0$?" That would be true if you believe that "$d\theta$ is close to $0$" means "$d\theta=0.$" But as long as $d\theta\neq0,$ if $d\theta$ is small then $sin(\frac12d\theta)$ will be much closer to $\frac12d\theta$ than to $0.$

Comment: @Mario $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ answers your question in comment.